# Partition Will Not Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 16.04, windows-10

I am dual booting Ubuntu and Win10 - my Ubuntu partition boots no problem, Win10 will get to the Loading screen where the dots make the circle, and I let it sit there for 3 hours before I did a hard reset.

I have booted into Ubuntu and attempted to run boot-repair 3 times, and each time it shows it as succesful, but when I reboot and attempt to boot into my Win10 partition I get the same outcome of circles.

Here is the output of `lsblk` and `sda1` is the trouble partition that I am unable to boot to:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 833.3G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   495M  0 part 
└─sda3   8:3    0  97.7G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

And the link provided by `boot-repair` is here if it will help anyone with more knowledge.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/16724898/

What must be done in order to repair my win10 partition?

Let me add that this issue did not occur until I upgraded to `Ubuntu 16.04`

Comment: Boot-Repair does not fix most Windows issues. Not related to Ubuntu. And you left Windows hibernated or its fast start up on. Since hibernated Linux cannot boot it from grub menu. Use Boot-Repair to temporarily restore a Windows MBR or use your Windows repair flash drive or installer to fixMBR. Turn off fast start. Then restore grub boot loader with Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 cases after hard reset:

1. install ubuntu first then ubuntu (which is not suggested to do and don't know about it)
2. install windows first then ubuntu (which i know and assume you followed)

According to your problem and as per my knowledge you must do a **boot-repair** using windows bootable usb stick that  sets the boot files in windows so that it can boot.

I am sorry that i am not expert to understand the link :(

Comment: How would I do a boot repair using windows bootable usb stick?

Comment: I used UBCD and replaced the MBR and PBR and this did not resolve.  How would I do a boot-repair as you describe?